# Error converting vector shapefile to raster (.TIF) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, vector, rasterization

I am working with a shapefile of 10km grid regions of the UK obtained from digimap.

[image]

I need to convert this to a raster in order to do some analysis in R regarding agricultural intensity of 10km UK sites.

Everytime I load the vector file in QGIS and do raster->conversion -> rasterize I get an error which reads:

The following layers were not correctly generated.

- /private/var/folders/q3/vldvgpt970g5mn1y_46n4jjr0000gn/T/processing_cf35adc2256045b9b004c26c6ce46245/94b6409973714574a8226988cee87064/OUTPUT.tif

You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

I know there are a lot of other questions about this but none of the answers have helped me to solve what I am trying to do.

Perhaps I am not inputting the correct parameters in the dialog box, could anyone help me with this? I've tried using layer extent and canvas extent in the output extent box and both have not worked.

[image: dialog box]

Comment: you can't have a resolution of 0 - try 100 or 1000 depending on how many pixels per cell you want

Comment: @IanTurton thanks! is it best to select canvas or layer extent? sorry I have never used QGIS before..!

Comment: either will be fine, canvas is what you are looking at, layer is all of the data

Comment: @IanTurton the command worked however I have no image, just a blank white space! any ideas?

Comment: @user2856 the only values in my attribute table are the names of the grid squares e.g. NT16, NT19 etc ?

Comment: @user2856 So I have this grid data and then a land cover map. In R I need to use the grainchanger package to convert the land cover map to 10km regions to be able to work out the % agriculture in each 10km square. For the grainchanger package my 10km grid squares need to be in a .TIF format instead of a shapefile. No idea if  this is the right way to go about it though..

Comment: @user2856 any value?

Comment: @user2856 1 gave me a small black square.. progress i suppose !

Comment: @user2856 it worked! thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use a value other than `0.0` for the burn-in value, such as `1.0`.
- Use the extent of the land cover raster or the 10km grid
- Change output raster size units to map instead of pixel,
- Specify 10000 (your map units are metres, i.e 10km) for the resolution.